# VBA Inserting Excel complexe spreadsheet in .doc document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

So I've been working on a word .dotm file that will combine several .doc and .xls documents into a single .pdf file.

Right now, I have two different problems, I will only detail the first one on this topic:

When inserting a complexe (very complexe) Excel sheet in my .doc document, the output is only a pile of meta data (Well mostly looks like it, if you prefer clearer language: it is a complete mess of characters and page breaks) instead of my file. I've looked for the entire day (really, I wasted my work day looking for answers) on the internet and even asked on MSDN forum (no answer at all) about this topic and everyone seems to have his code working like a charm.

Here is my code:

```
Sub MergeFiles()
    Documents.Open FileName:="C:\test_cea\02.doc"

    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\test_cea\03.doc"

    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\test_cea\04.xls"

    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="C:\test_cea\output.pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
    ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=doNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

I've tried a TREMENDOUS amount of things, from switching to opening the .xls first, to trying every single combination of parameters possible in my InsertFile() method and nothing works.
The most amusing part is: it works perfectly when trying to do it with Word UI, meaning Word can do it, but I'm doing it wrong somehow.

Comment: Could you please tell us exactly which commands you use in the Word UI for inserting the files (especially the xls). And did you try recording the steps in a Word macro to compare whether the syntax you're using is the same as Word uses for inserting the files?

Comment: Well, I'm using the Insert as Object to insert it in Word UI, problem is, I have to create a custom toolbar in VBA and make it work without having to use the insert as object from Word UI, meaning it must use a method from the word VBA reference. I cannot really use a macro, since I will need to deconstruct strings of text, and do complexe algorithms to determine if the file is to be merged or not.

Comment: InsertFile will not give you the same result as Insert/Object, so the "why" of your problem is clear enough. Do record the macro, as I suggested, so that you can see WHICH METHOD WORD NEEDS YOU TO USE! I'm not telling you to use a macro, but to use the result of the recorder for your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the final answer to that question:

As Word cannot interpret an Excel file it is not possible to force file insertion this way.

Instead use the following code:

```
Sub MergeFiles()

    Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim wdDocument As Word.Document

    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wdDocument = Documents.Open("mydoc.doc")

    appExcel.Workbooks.Open("myxls.xls")

    appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("Print_area").CopyPicture 'Copy picture prevents weird behavior from Word'

    Selection.PasteSpecial Placement:=wdInLine, DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture

End Sub
```

Obviously this is a sample code that will do the whole process but the idea is to copy the Print Area (one must be defined, you can also use Sheets(1).UsedRange but this will be a problem if the Excel file is oddly formatted) as picture and paste it into Word. You can also simply copy it and paste it but it may mess up your output table formatting.

I don't even know why people down voted my question -_-

Anyway, if you encouter the same issue, simply tell me if this code works.